# TextView in ScrollView - disable auto scroll on typig?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

Maybe the problem’s root is in me, but I can’t find an option for disabling the autoscroll on a `scrollview` that has a `textView` inside it.

Whenever the user enters a new line at the bottom of the scrollview’s visible area, and continues typing, the scrollview moves along

———-

It is not exaxtly a problem, the problem is that I can not set a “margin” for it preventing the overcrowded look of the UI elements

**Images:**

**(1) what it looks like now entering a new line at the bottom and typing / the scrollView autoscrolls to that pos /**

**(2) what it should look like**

[image]

What could I do?

Comment: Why exactly are you using a textview inside a scrollview?

Comment: It has its purpose, for good looking design

Comment: You can restrict the height of UITextView with constraints.

Comment: @AndrasKarpati: You don't really need to use TextView inside the UIScrollView. what I've suggested works for what you're trying to achieve. Im just not sure about the chunk of white space. If you tell me the use case, I'm sure I'll be able to give you the exact solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing something similar with UITextView, which has a specified initial height and keeps increasing the height with input text till a maximum specified height and then starts scrolling the text. Let me know is thats something you are looking for.

[image]
Single Line
[image]
Two lines
[image]
Three lines
[image]
Four lines
[image]
Stops increasing height

I am using the delegate method as below. The Height constraints in the below code are IBOutlets from Storyboard.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let maxSize = CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: 90.0)
    let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(maxSize)
    if estimatedSize.height <= 90 {
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textViewHeightConstraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
        textViewContainerHeightConstraint.constant = estimatedSize.height + 12.0
    } else {
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textViewHeightConstraint.constant = 90.0
        textViewContainerHeightConstraint.constant = 102.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Just put a container around it (UIView) and put the UITextView into this container. You can access this one by mytextView.superview...

---

Here is an example how you create the TextView with his Container...

```
// SuperView of textView
let container = UIView() 
self.scrollView.addSubview(container)

let textView = UITextView()
/*
your textView config
*/
container.addSubview(textView)
```

And just set a reference inside the TVs delegate method (dont forget to clear it if finished editing)

```
// Delegate of UITextView... 
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    activeTextView = textView
    currentIdentifier = textView.accessibilityIdentifier
}
```

This is a snippet inside an observer (KeyboardDidShow / Hide)

```
// activeTextView was defined inside textView
if activeTextView != nil { 
    // now you can access it via textview.superview?
    if let origin = activeTextView.superview?.frame.origin, let parentFrame = activeTextView.superview?.frame {
        if !aRect.contains(origin) {
            scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(parentFrame, animated:true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only working method was to add a view to the bottom of the textView.. don't really understand why